# Show pdf in android app without download it and without using web view

Tags: android, pdf, androidpdfviewer

I put a pdf file on the server. Now I want to show the pdf file in the Android application without downloading the file and without using the web view.
I found the library but it did not show anything and I do not know why !!
This Library is ->
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: You have of course to download the pdf from server to phone. And as a webview cannot display a pdf there is no reason to use a webview.

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidPdfViewer` needs to download the pdf file, the PDFjs library can support web-side access, and `WebView` loading "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +pdfUrl (pdf link)